# Make a google sheet checkbox value of cell X calculated as OR(X, Y) where Y is another checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a table of containing checkboxes:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | X | X |
|  | X |  |
|  |  |  |

I'd like columns B and C to either be checked if they are checked or both B and C checked if A is checked, is there a way to do this without using scripts?

Answer (score 0):

There's a thorough treatment of how to achieve check boxes controlled by other checkboxes without script on Ben Collins's excellent website here:
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-select-all-checkbox/

For your case as shown, if you can spare a row above the checkboxes you can try the following:

1. Add checkboxes to A2, B2, B3 & B4 using Data validation/Checkboxes. **You must** delete FALSE in the custom cell values option (i.e. unchecked must generate a null value)
2. In B1 add the following formula:

```
=if(A2,{{"";true;true},{"";true;""}},)
```

3. Hide/protect row 1 to protect the formula in B1 from any changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that does what I'm looking for on the sheet. What I would is row based "check all" where A2 to a checkbox that if checked B2, and C2 are checked. 

In the case of A3, it's not checked by B3 is still manually checkable

The A column I'd like to be usable as a "check the entire row to be checked" and also allow users to check individual columns too

Comment: If you want each checkbox in column A to act as a 'check all' for the checkboxes in the same row, that's also possible by employing a hidden column to the right of column A (i.e. the controlled checkboxes will be in column C&D). Let me know if this is what you want (I'm not quite sure from your comment) and if so I'll edit the answer.